# Facebook api for fconnect

Tags: facebook

I want to use facebook API at my website. First I tried to use it by using give sdk sample code in php. All is fine except getting email id after login. How I can get email id.

Secondly when I login at popup window after click on fconnect button, It remain in popup also.

It should get back on parent window instead of open last page in popup.

If anyone getting my question then kindly give me your idea to sort out this problem.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Getting the email address will be part of the `/me` Graph object using a user access token with the `email` permission accepted.  Play here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer to see the effects of access tokens with and without the `email` permission.

I would use the FB.login() call rather than the old fb connect button.  :) :)